# Trouble with CSS

Tags: html, css, media

I start learning coding this month with the book *Oh My Code* written by Sonia Baibou. I'm at a point when I'm do exactly the same thing, but it doesn't work. I've got my web page, and I'm trying to use Media query to adapt for small screen. I wrote this

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 414px) {
  #apropos{
    flex-direction: column;
    color: red;
  }
}
```

and

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

If you can help me, I will be grateful.

Comment: Please also show the relevant html code

Comment: Where is the HTML containing the element with ID "apropos"?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Also you can go [to tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question.

Comment: hello whats not working

Comment: when I see my web site on a small screen nothing is different, it's like what I wrote isn't here

Comment: i tried youre code its working fine have you testet your code here ?whats the path of youre style.css

Comment: I add my whole HTML and CSS in answer if you can take a look godfather. Because i really don't understand why. I'm on a MacBook and safari does it can make any difference ?

Comment: try to go to 600px in media query and check if it works on safari

Comment: thank you it work on safari with 600px. But why 600 and not 414 ?

Comment: @PierricEyquem i think even 500px work but try( max-device-width:414px) check if it works

Answer (score 1):

Try using only -> @media only screen ...

Comment: I try but it's he same, I add the full html in answer it may help. Thanks for your answer

Comment: I tried you're code and it works for me -> https://codepen.io/Felilx/pen/poyqGra

Answer (score 0):

try this one, when you resize the color of the text should change
if larger than 414px it will change to a different color and same the other way when it is less than 414px.

```css
    
h1{
color: red;
}

h5{
color: green
}

@media screen and (min-width: 414px) {
  h1{
    color: green;
  }
  h5 {
  color: blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1> hello <h1>

<h5> this might be helpful <h5>
```

Comment: it doesn't work either, I add my full HTML and CSS for your help

Answer (score 0):

I add my full html and css

```css
@font-face{
    font-family: 'Luna';
    src: url('./Luna.ttf');
}
 
 html{
    font-family: 'arial';
    font-size: 16px;
 }
*{
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
}

#hero{
    background:url('./fond.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    padding-bottom: 1%;
}

nav{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px
}

a{
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: 1s;
}
a:hover{
    font-size: 24px;
}
#bandeau{
    margin-top: 10%;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}

#contenu{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5%;
}

h1{
    font-family:'Luna';
}
#contenu a{
    color: red;
    border: 1px solid red;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding: 20px;
    transition: 1s;
}
#contenu a:hover{
    color: white;
    background-color: rgba(178,32,19,0.8);
}
#contenu img:hover{
    transition: 0.8s;
    transform: rotate(360deg) scale(3);
}

#apropos{
    display: flex;
}
#apropos_image{
    padding: 20px;
    flex: 1;
    max-width: 100%;
}
#apropos_texte{
    padding: 20px;
    flex: 2;
    text-align: justify;
}

#services{
    display: flex;
    background-color: #666;
    color: white;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
.services_items p{
    text-align: justify;
    padding: 20px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 414px) {
  #apropos{
    flex-direction: column;
    color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html> 

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>OhMyCode</title>
    <meta name="description" content="OhMYCODE! Je code mon premier site web"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/275443d32b.js" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
  </head>

  <body>
   <section id="hero">
    <nav>

     <a href="http://www.linkedin.fr" target="_blank"> Linkedin</a>
     <a href="http://www.monentreprise.fr" target="_blank">Mon Entreprise</a>
     <a href="monCV.pdf" target="_blank">MON CV</a>

    </nav>

    <div id="bandeau">
     <div id="contenu">

      <img src="MonLogo.png" alt="MonLogo" width="100"/>
      <h1>OhMyCode</h1>
      <h2>Je code mon premier site</h2>
      <h3>Toutes les infos ici</h3>
      <br/></br/>
      <a href="mailto:ohmycode@test.com?subject=Demande de Contact">Contactez-moi</a>

     </div>
    </div>

   </section>

   <section id="apropos">

     <div id="apropos_image">
      <img src="apropos_image.jpg">
     </div>

     <div id="apropos_texte">
       <p>Quid? qui se etiam nunc subsidiis patrimonii aut amicorum liberalitate sustentant, hos perire patiemur? An, si qui frui publico non potuit per hostem, hic tegitur ipsa lege censoria; quem is frui non sinit, qui est, etiamsi non appellatur, hostis, huic ferri auxilium non oportet? Retinete igitur in provincia diutius eum, qui de sociis cum hostibus, de civibus cum sociis faciat pactiones, qui hoc etiam se pluris esse quam collegam putet, quod ille vos tristia voltuque deceperit, ipse numquam se minus quam erat, nequam esse simularit. Piso autem alio quodam modo gloriatur se brevi tempore perfecisse, ne Gabinius unus omnium nequissimus existimaretur.Quid? qui se etiam nunc subsidiis patrimonii aut amicorum liberalitate sustentant, hos perire patiemur? An, si qui frui publico non potuit per hostem, hic tegitur ipsa lege censoria; quem is frui non sinit, qui est, etiamsi non appellatur, hostis, huic ferri auxilium non oportet? Retinete igitur in provincia diutius eum, qui de sociis cum hostibus, de civibus cum sociis faciat pactiones, qui hoc etiam se pluris esse quam collegam putet, quod ille vos tristia voltuque deceperit, ipse numquam se minus quam erat, nequam esse simularit. Piso autem alio quodam modo gloriatur se brevi tempore perfecisse, ne Gabinius unus omnium nequissimus existimaretur.hostibus, de civibus cum sociis faciat pactiones, qui hoc etiam se pluris esse quam collegam putet, quod ille vos tristia voltuque deceperit, ipse numquam se minus quam erat, nequam esse simularit. Piso autem alio quodam modo gloriatur se brevi tempore perfecisse, ne Gabinius unus omnium nequissimus existimaretur.hostibus, de civibus cum sociis faciat pactiones, qui hoc etiam se pluris esse quam collegam putet, quod ille vos tristia voltuque deceperit, ipse numquam se minus quam erat, nequam esse simularit. Piso autem alio quodam modo gloriatur se brevi tempore perfecisse, ne Gabinius unus omnium nequissimus existimaretur.hostibus, de civibus cum sociis faciat pactiones, qui hoc etiam se pluris esse quam collegam putet, quod ille vos tristia voltuque deceperit, ipse numquam se minus quam erat, nequam esse simularit. Piso autem alio quodam modo gloriatur se brevi tempore perfecisse, ne Gabinius unus omnium nequissimus existimaretur.
       </p>
     </div>

   </section>

   <section id="services">

     <div class="services_items">
       <i class="fas fa-graduation-cap fa-4x"></i>
       <p>Lorem Ipsum est un générateur de faux textes aléatoires. Vous choisissez le nombre de paragraphes, de mots ou de listes. Vous obtenez alors un texte aléatoire que vous pourrez ensuite utiliser librement dans vos maquettes.
       </p>
     </div>

     <div class="services_items">
      <i class="fas fa-chart-line fa-4x"></i>
       <p>Lorem Ipsum est un générateur de faux textes aléatoires. Vous choisissez le nombre de paragraphes, de mots ou de listes. Vous obtenez alors un texte aléatoire que vous pourrez ensuite utiliser librement dans vos maquettes.
       </p>
     </div>

     <div class="services_items">
      <i class="fas fa-trophy fa-4x"></i>
       <p>Lorem Ipsum est un générateur de faux textes aléatoires. Vous choisissez le nombre de paragraphes, de mots ou de listes. Vous obtenez alors un texte aléatoire que vous pourrez ensuite utiliser librement dans vos maquettes.
       </p>
     </div>

   </section>
  </body>

</html>
```